# How to collect pytest allure report after the test session?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using Allure + Pytest for tests execution. Right now I need to archive tests results, but I'm facing the fact that archive is created **before** the test run is finished.
I've tried to call pytest_sessionfinish, but archive is created **before** tests.log file is created:

```
pytest.ini content: log_file = report/allure-report/tests.log

    def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
        # Fixme, use https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish ?
        cmdName = 'tar -C %s -czf %s.tar %s ' % (SETTINGS.paths.report, basename(SETTINGS.paths.timestamp), SETTINGS.paths.report)
        LOGGER.info('Calling "%s" cmd to get archive' % cmdName)
        call(cmdName)
```

Also, I've tried to create a fixture with scope='session' and autouse=True, but it's called even before all Allure files are created.
Any ideas except creating a runner script, which will call pytest.main() and archive command after it?

Comment: Have you tried making a "teardown" fixture with `yield`? https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#teardown-cleanup-aka-fixture-finalization

Comment: Sure. There was a teardown fixture with scope='session' and autouse=True, but it's called even earlier than pytest_sessionfinish, so it's not a solution :)